# How is the force in Newtonian mechanics a covector field?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I am following Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, in which he considers $n$ particles with masses $m_1, \ldots, m_n$ and where the position of the $i$th particle is given by $q^i_1, q^i_2, q^i_3$. The time evolution of this system can be described as a curve in $\mathbb{R}^{3n}$:
$$q(t) = \big(q_2^1(t), q_2^1(t), q_2^1(t), \ldots, q_2^n(t), q_2^n(t), q_2^n(t)\big).$$
Letting $M = (M_{ij})$ denote the $3n \times 3n$ diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are
$$(m_1, m_1, m_1, m_2, m_2, m_2, \ldots, m_3, m_3, m_3)$$
and
$$F(q) = \big(F_1(q), \ldots, F_{3n}(q)\big)$$
the $3n$ components of the forces. Then from Newton's second law we have that
$$M_{ij}\ddot{q}^j(t) = F_i\big(q(t)\big)$$
where the summation convention has been applied. Lee remarks

> We assume that the forces depend smoothly on $q$, so we can interpret $F(q) = \big(F_1(q), \ldots, F_{3n}(q)\big)$ as the components of a smooth covector field on $Q$.

How is $F(q)$ a covector field? It seems we never uses tangent vectors above nor does $F$ act on them.

Comment: The following answer over at Physics SE seems relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/54948/55641

Comment: Well, the short answer is that you write the suffix downstairs $F_i$.  Long answer you examine how $F_i$ transforms under change of coordinates.

Comment: @user10354138 What vector is $F$ acting on for it to be a covector?

Comment: I think the symplectic structure of the cotangent bundle plays a role here. The motion of a particle in an manifold $M$ is described by a curve in $T^*M$, which satisfies a system of first order ODE's. This is most clearly stated using Hamiltonian mechanices. I'm not sure how to translate it all into Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: In Newtonian mechanics, we have $F$ is the one-form $-dV$ where $V=V(q)$ is the potential energy.  The other formulation that you are probably more familiar with, viz. $F=-\nabla V$, uses the Euclidean metric to raise the 1-form $dV$ to a vector field $\nabla V$.

Comment: @user10354138 Wouldn't this require our force to be conservative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to expand the discussion so far, in particular @Deane and @user10354138 comment on Hamilton/Newton mechanics. Forces would modify momentum, affecting $p$. I would recommend sections 3.11 and 3.12 of [Marsden and West](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/%7Emarsden/bib/2001/09-MaWe2001/MaWe2001.pdf) but I believe their equation (3.1.3) has an obvious typo, mixing $p$ and $q$, if you compare with equation 1.4.3 on page 377 of that article, and usual convention for Hamilton vector fields, for example [wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field). The equations should read
$$\dot{q} = X_{q}(q, p) = \frac{\partial{H}}{\partial p},\\
\dot{p} = X_{p}(q, p) = -\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial q} + f_H(q, p).
$$
In this system, if you follow the flow then the energy $H$ is not conserved but changed by
$$\frac{d}{dt}H(q(t), p(t)) =  \frac{\partial H}{\partial q}\dot{q}
+ \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\dot{p}
= \frac{\partial H}{\partial q}(\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial p}) + \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}(-\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial q} + f_H(q, p))
= \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}.f_H(q, p).
$$
Here, $\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}$ is tangent-like, so $f_H$ should be cotangent-like for the contraction gives us a scalar.

Also, $f_H(q, p)$ is an element of $T^*_qQ$ for the same reason for the affinity of connections. In general, if $E$ is a vector bundle over $Q$, if $(\Delta_q, \Delta_e)\in T_{q, e}E$ is a tangent vector at $(q, e)\in E$ and $e_1\in E$ projects to $q$ then $(\Delta_q, \Delta_e + e_1)$ is another tangent vector at $(q, e)\in E$. Take $E = T^*Q$, $e_1=f_H(q, p)$ in this case.

To answer what does $f_H$ acts on to be a covector, it pairs with $\dot{q}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}$ to be the rate of change of energy, I think it is called power.

Comment: Thank you, would this require that $f$ acts on velocities? If so, how would forces that do not depend on velocity become a one-form, for example gravity which only depends on position $q$?

Comment: So we write $f_H(q, p)$ since it *could be* but needs not be  dependent on $p$ (ie domain is $T^*Q$ but we could have $f(q,p_1) = f(q, p_2)$ for all $p_1, p_2$). However, the value $f_H(q, p)$ is in $T_q^*Q$ ( this is "fiber preserving map over the identity" in Marsden and West), so you can pair with a vector in $T_qQ$ to get a scalar.

Comment: Thank you. I am still a bit confused but maybe I will have to read Mardsen and West before continuing. At the moment the only justification I have for the force being a one-form is that so Newton's (or equivalently, Hamilton's) equations make sense. But I still don't see how the force is taking a vector as an input when the force is velocity independent.

Comment: Sure, it is basically the infinitesimal version of work = force times displacement. This should work for all kind of forces. So how do you calculate work/power on a sphere ? Force could lie anywhere in the ambient space but the effect on work/power is just $P = F.v$, ie given by a $1$-form, since $v$ is tangent to the sphere, while $F$ could be velocity dependent or not.

Comment: I see, so it is because the covector field is evaluated at both a point in the manifold and a vector in the tangent space? In other words, by defining a one-form that only depends on the point (and not the tangent vector) we can define velocity independent forces?

Comment: Yes, I think this is it.

Comment: Great, thank you for all your help!